# How to apply FILE in views field

Tags: views, 8, entities

I like to make a custom view for the module entity browser. For some reasons I do not want to install the module entity browser empamples.
But I make the experience as I created the view that there are no file options to select only content options.
Can anybody help?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is 'File' not available in the 'typ' dropdown at the top of the modal (that currently shows 'Alle'?

Comment: no 'File' is not available that's my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new view, you can choose on which entity the view is based on. In the first picture the view is based on *File*, in the second picture it is based on *Content* (nodes).

You only see the fields of that source you have selected.

Another method to get the fields from *File* would be to configure a relationship using a reference field. But this is then additional, you get fields from both tables by doing this.